# JSON ответ, flask

Tags: mysql, python, json, flask

Добрый день, получаю ответ,при использовании flask,в таком виде:

```
[
  [
    1, 
    "\u041b\u0438\u044f", 
    "\u0410\u0437\u0430\u043d\u0447\u0435\u0435\u0432\u0430", 
    "\u0420\u0443\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043d\u0430", 
    "alr", 
    "alr", 
    2, 
""
```

Но мне нужно получить примерно такую структуру с названием полей:

```
[
  [
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "\u041b\u0438\u044f", 
  и т.д.
```

Как это можно сделать?

```
@app.route("/")
def connect():
   cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM student")
   data = cursor.fetchall()
   return jsonify(data)
  # json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii = False)
```

И как решить вопрос с кодировкой при jsonify?

Comment: Первая часть вопроса к json или flask вообще не относится, во второй части вопроса непонятно какие именно проблемы с кодировкой

Comment: @andreymal я описываю проблему так,как понимаю сам. Проблема с кодировкой в том,что это должна быть кириллица.

Comment: `\u0410` это вполне кириллическая буква `А`, `\u0437` это вполне кириллическая `з` и так далее, я проблем с кодировками не вижу, это обыкновенный юникод :)

Comment: @andreymal да, это я понимаю,и этот ответ в клиенте на ангуляре отображается как надо, хотелось бы,чтобы и здесь отображалось в кириллице, как если бы я использовал закомменченную сточку с json.dump

Comment: @andreymal да и даже это я переживу, основная проблема для меня это структура JSON ответа)